# Execute my receiver before package installer

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to execute my code before an app get installed. i.e. whenever user download any app externally and click on icon of an app, before package installer I want show my activity or allow user to choose my application to run. 
Here is the sample image which is from Lookout app, I want to replicate same feature.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious security reasons, from a regular Android app.

You are certainly welcome to download the Android OS source code, modify it to contain your desired features, package the results into a ROM mod, and distribute that ROM mod. Convincing people to use your ROM mod may be a challenge.

Comment: But there are some apps like AppLocker which provides such functionality, so how it works actually?

Comment: @dhuma1981: There are over a dozen apps named "AppLocker" on the Play Store. Which are you referring to?

Comment: I am talking about https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock app, when i choose to lock install/uninstall, its lock screen popup to enter password whenever i want to install any app from my SD card, and if i provide correct password then package installer will be shown, other wise nothing happens.

Comment: I will work to have this security hole fixed. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: What about the solution of my problem?

Comment: @dhuma1981: There is no solution to your problem that does not involve a security hole or building your own ROM mod.